# How to find the domains which never open the emails in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Trying to find the way to get the list of domains which receive the emails but never open the email.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Where do you think it is most likely to find this type of information in SFMC? The community is here to help you, but we expect a certain degree of research being done before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this information by comparing the [_Sent](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5) data view with the [_Open](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5) data view (although note, that since the [iOS 15 update](https://blog.insycle.com/ios-15-email-open-tracking-data-privacy#:%7E:text=not%20limited%20to%3A-,Email%20Open%20Tracking%20Will%20End%20on%20iOS%2015%20Devices,email%20marketing%20metric%20for%20years.) came out, tracking opens is not a reliable metric anymore).

Once you have the list of subscribers that were sent, but did not open an email, you can use the [right()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_right.asp) sql function to get just the domains from email addresses:

```
SELECT
RIGHT(su.emailaddress, LEN(su.emailaddress) - CHARINDEX('@', su.emailaddress)) as Domain
FROM _Sent s INNER JOIN _Subscribers su
ON s.subscriberid = su.subscriberid
WHERE s.SubscriberKey NOT IN (SELECT SubscriberKey FROM _Open)
```